# Color each triangle on a ConvexHullMesh

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I'm using this code to show the convex hull of some points in 3D:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
p = {{6, 0, 0}, {0, 6, 4}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 5}, {9, 6, 0}, {3, 0, 7}};

chull = ConvexHullMesh[p];
Show[HighlightMesh[chull, Labeled[1, "Index"]], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[p, 0.05], Blue, 
   Map[Text[#, # + {0., 0, 0.001}] &, p]}], Axes -> True, 
 Boxed -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

I need to give every triangle a color or number so I can know it when I change the convex hull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
colors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[;; MeshCellCount[chull,2]]];
styledfaces = Style[{2, #}, colors[[#]]]& /@ Range[MeshCellCount[chull, 2]];

Show[HighlightMesh[chull, {Labeled[1, "Index"], styledfaces}], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[p, 0.05], Blue, Map[Text[#, # + {0., 0, 0.001}] &, p]}], 
  Axes -> True, Boxed -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

To get face colors with `Opacity[1]` use

```
colors = Opacity[1, #]& /@ ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[;; MeshCellCount[chull,2]]];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Can you help me to make every triangle not transparent such that when I see one I can not see  the one  behind it. I hope i explain it well.

Comment: @Ateq, please see the updated version.

Comment: Got it, thanks :)